# 18.04 - Joining AD problems

Tags: networking, 18.04, ldap

After a fresh install and update && upgrade, I have followed [this guide](https://bitsofwater.com/2018/05/08/join-ubuntu-18-04-to-active-directory/) to add the machine to our AD infrastructure, but after basic configuration `realm join -v [domain]` returns

```
! Can't contact LDAP server
realm: No such realm found
```

So I fired up a CentOS minimal VM and was able to register the machine through that. Cross-referencing the two outputs, I noticed that on Ubuntu the same `realm` command is querying the wrong IP when looking up the LDAP server, but I did not find any info on how to change that parameter in config files or through `man realm`.

So I tried `ldapsearch -h [server IP]`, manually specifying the server and this was returned:

```
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Local error (-2)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0))
```

which it should not be an issue since the same result is given by the CentOS VM, despite it joining successfully. So, I copied over from the CentOS machine the config files for krb5.conf, sssd.conf and realmd.conf (after a backup), but the same original error was given.

I believe that the wrong LDAP DSE lookup is the issue but I cannot find the parameter to change anywhere.

Thank you for all your help.

The AD server runs Windows Server 2016.
Providing .conf files below:

**krb5.conf**

```
[libdefaults]
    default_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
    dns_lookup_realm = true
    dns_lookup_kdc = true
    forwardable = true
    rdns = false    

[realms]
    MYDOMAIN.COM = {
                kdc = server.mydomain.com
                admin_server = server.mydomain.com
                default_domain = mydomain.com
    }

[domain_realm]
    .mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
    mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
```

**sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
domains = mydomain.com
config_file_version = 2


[domain/mydomain.com]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ad_domain = mydomain.com
krb5_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
```

**realmd.conf**

```
[users]
    default-home = /home/%D/%U
    default-shell = /bin/bash

[active-directory]
    default-client = sssd
    os-name = Ubuntu
    os-version = 18.04

[service]
    automatic-install = no

[mydomain.com]
    fully-qualified-names = yes
    automatic-id-mapping = no
    user-principal = yes
    manage-system = yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing my own solution as a full guide.

**DISCLAIMER:** I collated different answers on this site and added my own bits. I am also assuming su privileges throughout the guide.

### Join AD network with Ubuntu 18.04

**0)** Make sure that `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` files contain addresses and names according with your credentials provided by your domain admin. Also install the following packages:

```
$ apt install -y realmd sssd sssd-tools libnss-sss libpam-sss krb5-user adcli samba-common-bin
```

*Note:* When you install kerberos a prompt to insert your realm and domain names is given. Follow through, but leave empty if you do not know some bits.

**1)** Disable systemd-resolved

```
$ systemctl disable systemd-resolved.service
$ systemctl stop systemd-resolved
```

*Note:* this is the way I have found but it might be not ideal for you to disable systemd-resolved.

**2)** Add the following to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` in the `[main]` section:

```
dns=default
```

**3)** Remove the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf`. It will be recreated with the correct values.

**4)** Restart network service and add dnsmasq package:

```
$ service network-manager restart
$ apt install dnsmasq
```

**5)** In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` replace hosts line with this:

```
hosts: files dns [NOTFOUND=return] mdns4_minimal mdns4
```

*Note:* If you have problems, try this line instead `hosts: files dns myhostname`.

**6)** Add the following to `/etc/krb5.conf`. It is case-sensitive, so watch out. Also remove everything else (backup the default first `$ cp /etc/krb5.conf /etc/krb5.conf.bak`). If a section is not there, add it yourself:

```
[libdefaults]
default_realm = YOUR.REALM.NAME
dns_lookup_realm = false
dns_lookup_kdc = false
default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}
rdns = false
ticket_lifetime = 24h
renew_lifetime = 7d
forwardable = true

[realms]
YOUR.REALM.NAME = {
  kdc = your.realm.name
  admin_server = your.realm.name
}

[domain_realm]
your.realm.name = YOUR.REALM.NAME
.your.realm.name = YOUR.REALM.NAME
```

*Note:* forcing lookups off, greatly helps for debugging and generally I have found it really useful to see what is going on, contrary to basically all other guides on the topic. Also the reverse dns line `rnds` might be relevant only to my network setup, so try a value of `true` if some problem happens.

**7)** Check `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to include the following. Same guidelines and restrictions apply from point 6). Some values might be already set:

```
[sssd]
domains = your.realm.name
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/your.domain.name]
ad_domain = your.domain.name
krb5_realm = YOUR.DOMAIN.NAME
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli 
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
```

**8)** Reboot

**9)** Join your domain (*needs admin credentials*. You will be asked the admin password):

```
$ realm join -v --user=[admin_username] your.realm.name
```

*Note:* The `-v` tag for verbose is basically essential to see what could go wrong. At this point, if you actually pass the discovery step (always the first step of the `join` command), you will have some pretty detailed errors to follow if something happens and the worst should be gone.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Great that you share! I had the same initial problem:

```
realm: No such realm found:
```

I was following these guides:

- https://computingforgeeks.com/join-ubuntu-debian-to-active-directory-ad-domain/
- https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_18.04&p=realmd

My problem was solved by two smaller actions:

1. The new netplan settings file made by the installation looked like this:

   ```
   cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml:
   ```

   It was like that:

   ```
   network:
     ethernets:
       enp0s4:
           addresses:
           - 192.168.1.8/24
           gateway4: 192.168.1.3
           nameservers:
               addresses:
               - 192.168.1.252
               - 192.168.1.253
               - 192.168.1.3
               - 1.1.1.1
               search:
               - domain.loc
   version: 2
   ```

   When I swapped to my old proven setting structure, it looks like this:

   ```
   network:
     ethernets:
       enp0s4:
           dhcp4: no
           addresses: [192.168.1.8/24]
           gateway4: 192.168.1.3
           nameservers:
             addresses: [192.168.1.252,192.168.1.253,192.168.1.3,1.1.1.1]
   version: 2
   ```

   The latter example is what I needed to get it to function.
2. Disable IPv6 - (Maybe this was not causing the initial problem, but I disabled it before trying the netplan solution so I had it already adjusted so I want to share it.)

   I changed these two lines in `/etc/default/grub` and added `ipv6.disable=1`:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="ipv6.disable=1"
   ```

   And ran `update-grub`.

Answer (score 0):

I have two machines both running Kubuntu, and a Nethserver (CentOS) server running a Samba 4 AD server.

One of the client machines is older and has been updated several times. The other client machine has reasonably new install of Kubuntu 19.10 on it.

For some reason, domain logins stopped working on the older machine. I have been going through the configuration on both machines to see where they differ.

The new machine does not have a krb5.conf or a realmd.conf. The older machine does. Somehow, in the sssd.conf file, the line

```
ldap_id_mapping = True
```

had been changed to false.

I have removed the two config files and changed the ldap_id_mapping value back to True, and things seem to be back to normal. If you are having trouble, maybe remove the files and try the defaults. Might at least narrow down the source of the problem.